# Deny HTML in WebAPI model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I've been searching for this for a while, and couldn't find anything, apologies if there is something and I've missed it.

Is there anything in the Web-API 2 framework that will automatically reject HTML tags on string model properties (except for a select few)?

I know I could create a custom validation attribute, and whack it on every property, but that's a lot of over head to maintain and remember to do on all new models.

```
public class Person {
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    // ... snipped
}
```

I can make a post request to my `POST` endpoint with JSON similar to:

```
{
    "name": "<h1>This is my name</h1>"
}
```

In the action the `person.Name` will be equal to `"<h1>This is my name</h1>"`, with no validation errors raised

Comment: Why do you think the value "<h1>This is my name</h1>" should raise a validation error when your type is a string? Why would you want to / expect html tags inside strings to be stripped out?
If they come from user inputted strings, you should store them as is. You only need to make sure to proprely encode the data when inserting into sql or rendering a html page, but you need to do those things (ie, sql parameters, html encodes, etc) either way by default.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be a default OOB setup, but I'd be surprised if no-one else has wanted this same behaviour. We of course encode all the data where necessary, but we still want to kick out the html up front too

Comment: Imho, it's just not that often that you actively expect someone to input html, but then want to strip it out and ignore it. So your question, realistically, becomes about stripping out html from c# strings, and is not at all related to webapi, model binding, etc. Then you simply create a custom attribute to hook up the html stripping logic to all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing as you. Coming from a MVC standpoint where we have parameters to disallow html in input fields in forms, this seems reasonable.

I found this library tho, that sort of, in a way might help out... It does not fully answer your question in the way you want it, but it helps out with the custom attributes you would otherwise have to generate by yourself, if you decided to go for an attribute path...

Nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ASPNetWebAPIAntiXss/

Examples and the product page:
https://bitbucket.org/embarr-development/asp.net-web-api-antixss-attribute