# How to avoid AntiXSS and Script injection in MVC web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, umbraco7

I need your help to avoid AntiXSS and Script injection in MVC web api. I am using $http (angularjs) to post data on web api.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? How is this relevant and what extras do you need besides the built in protection?

Comment: I have web api and calling this api from angularjs service using $http.post. I want to prevent AntiXSS and Script injection to this api.

Comment: See if this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076978/deny-html-in-webapi-model-properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny HTML in WebAPI model properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076978/deny-html-in-webapi-model-properties)